# Show only clicked element values from multiple ng-click events angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have 10 more ng-click events, but i want to show only clicked element value where i have to change, but i updated in code there was so many true or false duplicates i have to write, pls help me that have to show only clicked ng-show values without using 'true or false' booleen functions in each click event.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.field = {single: 'untitled',single2:'default',single3:'enter'};

    $scope.addName1 = function (index) {
        var name1html = '<fieldset id="name1" ng-click="selectName1($index)"><label ng-bind-html="field.single"></label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"><button ng-click="removeName1($index)">-</button></fieldset>';
        var name1 = $compile(name1html)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(name1);
    };
    $scope.removeName1 = function (index) {
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#name1'));
        myEl.remove();
    };
    $scope.selectName1 = function (index) {
        $scope.showName1 = true;
        $scope.showName2 = false;
        $scope.showName3 = false;
    };
    
    $scope.addName2 = function (index) {
        var name2html = '<fieldset id="name2" ng-click="selectName2($index)"><label ng-bind-html="field.single2"></label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"><button ng-click="removeName2($index)">-</button></fieldset>';
        var name2 = $compile(name2html)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(name2);
    };
    $scope.removeName2 = function (index) {
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#name2'));
        myEl.remove();
    };
    $scope.selectName2 = function (index) {
        $scope.showName2 = true;
        $scope.showName1 = false;
        $scope.showName3 = false;
    };
    
    $scope.addName3 = function (index) {
        var name3html = '<fieldset id="name3" ng-click="selectName3($index)"><label ng-bind-html="field.single3"></label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"><button ng-click="removeName3($index)">-</button></fieldset>';
        var name3 = $compile(name3html)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(name3);
    };
    $scope.removeName3 = function (index) {
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#name3'));
        myEl.remove();
    };
    $scope.selectName3 = function (index) {
        $scope.showName3 = true;
        $scope.showName1 = false;
        $scope.showName2 = false;

    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

 </head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <div id="drop"></div>

 <button ng-click="addName1($index)">Name1</button>
  <button ng-click="addName2($index)">Name2</button>
 <button ng-click="addName3($index)">Name3</button>
 
  <form ng-show="showName1">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Field Label(?)</label>
   <br/>
   <input ng-model="field.single">
  </div>
 </form>
  <form ng-show="showName2">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Field Label(?)</label>
   <br/>
   <input ng-model="field.single2">
  </div>
 </form>
   <form ng-show="showName3">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Field Label(?)</label>
   <br/>
   <input ng-model="field.single3">
  </div>
 </form>

</body>

</html>
```

here is plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/oFytWlQMIaCaeakHNk71?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You will need "ng-repeat" in the HTML. Set an Array on $scope and let the template determine what HTML elements to add. Typically, $index is only set by ng-repeat.

Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thank you Andrew, i tried but i'm not getting result properly, can u pls edit the code in plunkr